# Create local remote repository using Maven

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

I am using Maven for build and Jenkins for CI/CD. For production, need to keep all my Maven build jars in my remote repository, I am adding my local repository by

```
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <url>http://10.16.70.55:9001/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>snapshots</id>
        <name>Archiva Managed Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>http://10.16.70.55:9001/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/repository</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
```

Is this the correct way? Does Jenkins provide remote repository? Is there any other tools which we can use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at using an actual repository manager tool like [Nexus OSS](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/download) or [JFrog Artifactory](https://jfrog.com/open-source/#artifactory) ?